# How to decrease width of dropdownbutton list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I needed a way to make dropdownmenu's width less than dropdownbutton's. I wanted the button to be larger and be visible when you open the menu. if I wrap the dropdownbutton in a Container the button will also get smaller and would be hard to tap on.

here's my code:

```
Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: widgetHeight,
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
              onChanged: (String? val) { 
              },
              iconEnabledColor: Colors.transparent,
              iconSize: 0.0,
              items: list
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((e) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: e,
                  child: Container(
                    child: StatefulBuilder(
                      builder:
                          (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              e,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize:
                                      20.0),
                            ),
                            value: getList()
                                        .indexWhere(
                                            (element) => element == e) >=
                                    0
                                ? true
                                : false,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setSelectedCheckBox(
                                  e, value!);
                              setState(() {});
                            });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList()),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

In DropdownButton I added `elevation: 0,` and `dropdownColor: Colors.transparent,` then I Added `color` and `width` to my Container under `items`.

here's the new code:

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: widgetHeight,
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
          elevation: 0,
          dropdownColor: Colors.transparent,
          onChanged: (String? val) { 
          },
          iconEnabledColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconSize: 0.0,
          items: list
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((e) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: e,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                color: Color(0xff545454),
                child: StatefulBuilder(
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                    return CheckboxListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          e,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize:
                                  20.0),
                        ),
                        value: getList()
                                    .indexWhere(
                                        (element) => element == e) >=
                                0
                            ? true
                            : false,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setSelectedCheckBox(
                              e, value!);
                          setState(() {});
                        });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    ),
  )
```